# Winform - Not WPF - ListView Currency and Checkbox with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, checkbox

Does anyone know how to add a currency to a specific column in ListView, please?
It is easy with WPF but my project is Win form.

**CheckBox**
I used this code for checkbox, but it only shows checkbox in the first Column. 
I want it on 5th Column

```
listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
```

Currency
I tried this but it is not good.

```
                ListViewItem viewItem = new ListViewItem(new string[]
                {

                    "£"+emailDetails.Total+".00"
                 });
```

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions at once. Edit the question to concentrate on one question and open a new topic for the other question.

Answer (score 0):

ListView in WinForms is a very different animal than ListView in WPF.

For the **currency**: add a string property to your `emailDetails` class that formats the currency as desired.  I would recommend you format the value once, when you set the Total amount, and then reuse the formatted value in the getter of the new property.

For the **checkbox**: the only way to have it in a different column than the first is to do [custom drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw?view=netframework-4.8) and draw the combobox yourself.  It is more complicated, as you will need to perceive clicks to change the picture of the box, and store the status of every checkbox somewhere.